# Remotely working on iMac, but with screen darkened

Tags: imac, display, remote-control

I have my main iMac in my kids room (little house, alas) and often I have to work late at night; I'd like to connect from my MacBook to the iMac keeping the screen black, as in sleep mode. Is there any sort of magic to achieve this? What if I plug a Mini DisplayPort cable? Will it exclude the monitor?
Thanks,
Guido

Comment: If you use Apple Remote Desktop tools, it is possible to lock the screen, displaying a static image over a black screen, while working on it remotely. Someone may be able to hack together a solution for you that kicks off this screen lock process while you connect with Screen Sharing, but personally I'm a fan of EmmEff's solution.

Answer (score 2):

You might be overlooking a simpler solution: throw a sheet/blanket/whatever over the display before you walk out of the room.

Comment: My iMac has a ventilation slot on the back near the top. This should not be covered or the machine could overheat.

Comment: Unfounded worry, IMHO, but if one is that worried, it'd be easy enough to fabricate some sort of physical screen blocking apparatus that does not block the port.

Comment: Fair enough; the current iMac user guide does not warn against blocking the ventilation openings, although that is still my advice!

Comment: Further to that, I cannot imagine a common bed sheet would completely block the ventilation port enough to make any significant difference.

Answer (score 0):

Lion has the ability to do a virtual desktop from one mac to another.
Maybe the following works:

- Create a second user account on the iMac, with 'sleep display'
  properties set.
- Make that account the active account on the iMac, and wait for it to
  go to sleep.
- Then use share screen on the MacBook to connect with a virtual
  desktop to your own account on the iMac.

I am not sure the iMac won't wake up when you virtually connect to it, but it's worth a try.